# Error connecting Ruby with SQL Server 2005

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, ruby

I am trying to connect SQL Server 2005 with Ruby using this code:

```
 con  = DBI.connect(DBI:ODBC:"SQLNCLI.1":"DESKTOP- 
 PA2K41U\SQLEXPRESS";"ruby_ch")
 sth = con.prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_test1")
 sth.execute()
```

The error is here:

```
PS C:\Users\pc\Documents> ruby t16.rb
t16.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL
con  = DBI.connect(DBI:ODBC:"SQLNCLI.1":"DESKTOP-PA2K41U\S
                        ^
t16.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting end-of-input
PA2K41U\SQLEXPRESS";"ruby_ch")
```

Comment: Those arguments should be strings based on [this](https://zhongxiao37s-wiki.readthedocs.io/en/latest/programming/ruby/DBI.html). Try something like: `con = DBI.connect("DBI:ODBC:SQLNCLI.1", "DESKTOP-PA2K41U\SQLEXPRESS", "ruby_ch")`

Comment: E:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/dbd-odbc-0.2.5/lib/dbd/odbc/driver.rb:36:in `rescue in connect': IM002 (0) [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data
source name not found and no default driver specified (DBI::DatabaseError)
        from E:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/dbd-odbc-0.2.5/lib/dbd/odbc/driver.rb:15:in `connect'
        from E:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi/handles/driver.rb:33:in `connect'
        from E:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi.rb:148:in `connect'
 why this Error came and how can i sove it

Comment: That's better than a syntax error--check your data source name, ensure SQL Server is up and driver specified.